# Hiding removing SubView from a different file in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am loading a progress view from this file into a different view controller, it is displaying fine but It will not remove. I've tried isHidden, removeFromSuperview(), making the alpha=0, but nothing is working. How can I get rid of it?

```
func timerAction(){

        let progressHUD = ProgressHUD(text: "Taking Reading")
        if(timerCounter <= 20){
            self.vc!.view.addSubview(progressHUD)
            timerCounter += 1
        } else {
            timer.invalidate()
            timerCounter = 0
            progressHUD.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }


self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.timerAction), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Comment: Does this method is called multiple times with timer?

Comment: the timer repeats, but is only called once

Comment: Have you tried removing it from its superview in the view controller where it is also created as subview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time the timer is called a new subview is added to the view controller. Add the subview 'progressHUD' just once and update it instead.